# how to prevent php function file_get_contents to truncate my request

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I use file_get_contents to send a request to a web service, let say:
https://example.com/mywebservice?arg1=value1&arg2=value2

If value2 is avaluewith#sometextafter, I send:
https://example.com/mywebservice?arg1=value1&arg2=avaluewith#sometextafter

My problem is that when the web server processes the request, it gets arg2=avaluewith

The pound character and what is after is lost.

How to correct that?

Answer (score 1):

THe URL's `hash` is never sent to the webserver. It exists solely client-side.

Comment: Probably encode the `hash` with `%23` but unsure about how would the webservice react to it.

Answer (score 0):

I added urlencode() to the param which was truncated and it works fine.

Now the full URL with full params is received and processed by the web service.